# R - matrix per timestamp data format (multidim timeseries)

Tags: r, multidimensional-array, time-series

I've searched a while for a 3D data format, where 1st dim would be timestamp like xts and 2nd two a matrix. There was a solution close enough [R - store a matrix into a single dataframe cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13504764/r-store-a-matrix-into-a-single-dataframe-cell) but i want to have the `xts` object instead of data frame. So here it goes:

```
myDF = data.frame(PnL=I(list()) )
myDF[[1, 'PnL']] <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3,dimnames = list(NULL,c("x1","x2","x3")))
myDF[[2, 'PnL']] <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3,dimnames = list(NULL,c("x1","x2","x3")))
myDF[[3, 'PnL']] <- matrix(rnorm(9), 3, 3,dimnames = list(NULL,c("x1","x2","x3")))
```

i can nicely access the elements by `myDF[[1]]`, however i want `xts` style so i convert:

```
timestamps = as.Date("2016-01-01") + 0:2
ts_array = xts(myDF, order.by = timestamps)
```

And here the problems start:

```
> ts_array
Error in coredata.xts(x) : currently unsupported data type
> ts_array[["2016-01-01"]]
NULL
```

`zoo` is a bit better, however i still cannot access by timestamp:

```
> ts_array
           PnL      
2016-01-01 Numeric,9
2016-01-02 Numeric,9
2016-01-03 Numeric,9
> ts_array[["2016-01-01"]]
NULL
```

Appreciate your ideas :)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you want this to be an `xts` object? Why not an old-fashioned named list?

Comment: Reason is to use `xts` specific expressions like `ts["2010/2016"]` for convenience.